# Double Thresholding in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm looking for  Double thresholding for segmentation!
I have to do this algorithm in matlab,but I couldn't find any source !!

Double Thresholding:

(1) Select two thresholds T1 and T2.

(2) Partition the image into three type regions :

R1, containing all pixels with gray values below T1.

R2, containing all pixels with gray values between T1 and T2 , inclusive.

R3, containing all pixels with gray values above T2.

where R1=core region, R2= fringe(intermediate, transition) region, R3=background.

(3) Visit each pixel in region R2. If the pixel has a neighbor in region R1, then reassign the pixel to region R1.

(4) Repeat step 3 until no pixels are reassigned.

(5) Reassign any pixels left in region R2to R3.

this Image show what I want : http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3636/3ihhmzgb_jpg.htm

how can I do that ?! please Help me .

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Good luck on your homework!

Comment: Let me ask a basic question here. You said and let me quote your words - `"reassign the pixel to region R1"`. Now how can you assign a pixel a value of a region of pixels? Do you mean the first match of `R1` if there are multiple matches? If so, how would you define the "first match"?

Comment: @Divakar: I believe what the OP means is that if a pixel in Region `R1` that is less than the threshold of `T1` is a neighbour of a pixel in Region `R2` which is within the range of `T1 <= t <= T2`, **reassign** the pixel so that this pixel in `R2` now belongs to `R1`.  FWIW, this is very craptacular wording.

Comment: @rayryeng So the only way that would make sense to me would be to assume `R1`, `R2` and `R3` as logical matrices, because otherwise when reassigning how do we decide what values do we assign to that particular pixel in Region `R1`,as there can be as many as 8 neighbours from `R2`.

Comment: @Divakar yes that's what I assumed as well. It makes sense in the end anyway. Thresholded images are binary in nature. What I did was all neighbours in the vicinity of a pixel in R2 get mapped to R1. The OP is pretty unclear and I think I'll stop visiting this post until we get more info. Classic dump and run poster.

Comment: @rayryeng Well OP says - `R1, containing all pixels..`, so it seemed not so obvious to me to assume R1, R2 and R3 as binary matrices.

Comment: @Divakar: Yup... Totally get what you're saying. This double thresholding algorithm is a bit unorthodox TBH. This is slightly different than what I remember but in the end you get two binary maps... At least you're supposed to. I put all these regions as binary matrices to make processing easier. OP: when are you going to show up and start talking?

Comment: @rayryeng I think we are past the HW deadline ;)

Comment: @Divakar: hahahahaha that made me laugh.  Thank you :)

Comment: I think that the algorithm is intended to have some "hysteresis" in the threshold. Any contiguous area from T1 and up that includes at least one pixel about T2 becomes region 2; everything else becomes region 1.

Comment: First of that Thank you for all Comment :)

Comment: @ Rafael I've done thresholding on binary image But result showed 2 region , In this homework I want 3regin

Comment: @ Divakar ,rayryeng answered your question "means is that if a pixel in Region R1 that is less than the threshold of T1 is a neighbour of a pixel in Region R2 which is within the range of T1 <= t <= T2, reassign the pixel so that this pixel in R2 now belongs to R1."

Comment: @,rayryeng , Thank you for your attention !
I'm trying to get result of your code.

Comment: @Hanieh So `R1`, `R2` and `R3` are all binary matrices, right?

Comment: @Hanieh: Since this is homework, I would like to have 90% of whatever mark you get.  It's only fair ;).  I've also edited my post.  Be advised that I have **not** tested it.  If it doesn't work, I'll leave that to you to figure out.  This algorithm was coded in a way that made sense to me.  If you're not getting the intended results, well I guess you'll have to do it on your own, won't you? :)

Comment: @ rayryeng :I know ;)
this is one of the my course exersices,and I have to do that in matlab! 
the exercise havae a lena Picture and we must do Double thresholding on that.
please see the this Link: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3636/3ihhmzgb_jpg.htm

Comment: @Hanieh: MATLAB is a good thing.  Consider yourself lucky!  That code that I wrote (without any comments) took between 10-12 lines, assuming you place all simple assignments in a single line.  If you wrote it in C or Java, I guarantee it would take > 100.  Also, that image is quite useful.

Comment: @Divakar :I think this pic is can be  useful:http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3636/3ihhmzgb_jpg.htm

Comment: @Hanieh: Finished.  This should hopefully work.  Bear in mind that if the output is not what you expect, that'll be your job to figure out.  I think it's safe to say that I have done more than expected for a typical SO member.

Comment: @  rayryeng , great thanks for all your work :)

Comment: @rayryeng You clearly did a great job indeed. You know some answers do take much more effort than many others for the same rep, but then the appreciation from OP and from within for yourself is something that covers up I think. `S0` is proud to have you!! :)

Comment: @Hanieh Thank you for the pic, it makes sense now. Maybe edit your question with it? Finally it could turn out as a great question, because you know people like photos :)

Comment: @Divakar: Hahaha thank you sir :) That means a lot coming from you!

Comment: @rayryeng Sorry that totally sounded like a talk, after looking back at it hehe! But hey I meant every bit of it!

Comment: @Hanieh: The picture describes that you want your image segmented into three regions.  However, in your algorithm that you have described, after we are finished, `R2` will contain **no pixels**.  The key point is where you mention that anything left in `R2` should go to `R3`.  As such, all of the meaningful information is in `R1` and `R3` but not in `R2`.  That picture is actually misleading.

Comment: @rayryeng Exactly true, My problem is that :(
But I don't know which one is wrong!? the algorithm or picture?
I've searched about Double Thresholding algorithm But I couldn't find any thing useful

Comment: @Hanieh: I have two questions to ask you.  (1) Where did you find the description of this algorithm?  (2) How did you convince yourself that the picture is the right algorithm?  Because if the picture is what you are looking for, then all you need is Step #1 and Step #2 from your algorithm.  If it isn't, then the picture is wrong.

Comment: @rayryeng  : unfortunately this image and algorithm in my teacher PowerPoint!
But I searched and I couldn't find any thing source  
I found that algorithm on some places such as Gonzales Book(have little details about 2 threshold)and other PowerPoint for someone else about double threshold (that I found in Internet) ,the algorithm have found in more than one places but the picture no! 
I don't have any strong experience in image processing so , I though  that can be possible.

Comment: I believe that the picture illustrates Steps #1 and #2.  However, the final steps do not reflect what the picture is describing.  In that case, then my code should be fine.  BTW, did you even try any of our solutions?

Comment: Yes I did. But I have a Error in Reshape Function

Comment: @Hanieh: I fixed it.  I've also ran it on my own and I'll put some image results up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have an image stored in the variable called `im`.  It is also assumed that `im` is in double format `[0-1]`.  Let's step through each part one at a time, with accompanying code.

> (1) Select two thresholds T1 and T2.

Let's say `T1 = 0.1` and `T2 = 0.7`.  We need to make sure that these thresholds are at the lower and higher end of the intensity spectrum.

```
T1 = 0.1;
T2 = 0.7;
```

> (2) Partition the image into three type regions :
>   R1, containing all pixels with gray values below T1.
>   R2, containing all pixels with gray values between T1 and T2, inclusive.
>   R3, containing all pixels with gray values above T2.
>   where R1=core region, R2= fringe(intermediate, transition) region, R3=background.

We will create **three** binary maps that will tell us where in the image each of these conditions are satisfied.

```
R1 = im < T1;
R2 = im >= T1 & im <= T2;
R3 = im > T2;
```

> (3) Visit each pixel in region R2. If the pixel has a neighbor in region R1, then reassign the 
>   pixel to region R1.

I'm going to assume **8-connectedness**, which means that a neighbour would be N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, or NW, using cardinal directions.  What we can do is take each overlapping neighbourhood of pixels for `R2` and place them into columns.  Do the same for `R1`.  We can use the function called `im2col` to help us do that.  **8-connectedness** checks for neighbours within a 3 x 3 pixel neighbourhood.  What's cool about `im2col` is that the for the output of this function, **middle** row will contain the centre of each neighbourhood.  We will definitely need this when we want to reconstruct our regions back.  When we extract the centre of each neighbourhood, it's just a matter of checking to see if:

1. If the centre of each neighbourhood in region `R2` evaluates to `true`
2. Any pixels in the corresponding neighbourhood of `R1` evaluates to `true`, then these are all neighbours of `R2`.

```
     %//Zero-pad the regions so we can check the borders
     R1 = padarray(R1, [1 1], 'replicate');
     R2 = padarray(R2, [1 1], 'replicate');

     %//Transform into columns
     B1 = im2col(R1, [3 3]);
     B2 = im2col(R2, [3 3]);

     %//Extract size for later
     [rows cols] = size(R1); 

     %// Extract centre of each neighbourhood
     middleB2 = B2(5,:);

     % // Find the indices of those neighbourhoods that have 1 in the centre
     windowsHaving1 = find(middleB2 == 1);

     % // Access the corresponding neighbourhoods in R1
     % // If ANY of them have a pixel of 1, then we know
     % // these locations from R2 need to go back to R1
     % // In that case, all you really have to do is take whichever
     % // pixels are true, and set them to true in R1

     % // See which neighbourhoods in `R1` have any pixels that are 1
     % // given the corresponding region in R2
     finalColumns = any(B1(:,windowsHaving1), 1);

     % // Grab the indices of these columns
     finalColumnsIndex = windowsHaving1(finalColumns);

     % // Reasign those pixels that are neighbours to R1     
     B1(5, finalColumnsIndex) = 1;
     B2(5, finalColumnsIndex) = 0;

     %// Restructure back - Recall this image is padded
     %// We took the rows and columns of the padded image
     %// and so we need to subtract each dimension by 2
     R1 = reshape(B1(5,:), rows-2, cols-2);
     R2 = reshape(B2(5,:), rows-2, cols-2);
```

> (4) Repeat step 3 until no pixels are reassigned.

Already performed.

> (5) Reassign any pixels left in region R2 to R3.

That's pretty straight forward.  Any pixels that are true in `R2`, simply turn these on in `R3`.

```
R3 = R2 | R3;
```

As such, your final double thresholded images are left in `R1` and `R3`.  If you want to create an integer map that tells you which pixels are in what region, you can do something like:

```
map = zeros(size(im));
map(R1) = 1;
map(R3) = 2;
```

Any pixels that are 0 did not meet the criteria after you went through the double threshold process.  As a test, let's take a look at this on a regular image.  I'll be using `cameraman.tif` that is in the MATLAB path.  As such, load in your image like so:

```
im = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
```

After, run through my code.  These are the results I get.  White pixels belong to the corresponding region, while black pixels don't.

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: I have a problem with this part of code in matlab :
 R1 = reshape(B1(5,:), rows, cols);
 R2 = reshape(B2(5,:), rows, cols);

"Error using reshape :To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change."
How can I debug it?

Comment: I know why. Give me a few minutes to change it

Comment: @Hanieh: I decided to run the code on my own computer.  I fixed some syntax errors.  I think the result is good!  Now if you don't mind, please accept my answer ;)  Click on the checkmark on the left side of my post when you scroll up to the top of it.

Comment: @Divakar: Decided to test my algorithm.  Results are above.

Comment: Nice touch to run the algorithm and show the result. And thanks for fixing the typos in mine!

Comment: @Floris: ahaha you're welcome.  I fixed the two that were obvious to me.  Glad you didn't mind!  I'm pretty sure that program will run.

Comment: @rayryeng wow! That's me, but I have a different tripod ;), awesome!

Comment: @rayryeng   vaoh! it's really good :)
great thanks for your strong help !

Comment: Note - I chose not to use `im2col` since it requires the image processing toolbox, and not everyone has that. If you _do_ have it, then you have a wide range of options available to you... so the question becomes "are you trying to perform a task, are you trying to learn to write Matlab, or are you trying to become familiar with tools in the IP toolbox". The "best" approach to this question is definitely a function of the answer to that question...

Comment: @Floris: I totally didn't consider that the OP doesn't have the IP toolbox.  I used it because it made my life easier, but you are definitely correct about what question to ask.  My gut feeling is the OP wants to solve this question and get it over with.... so it's really not a choice of either 1 or 2.... it's a question of "How can I find the source code for this question as fast as possible, and which sucker is going to do it for me?"  The answer to that question is me and you of course!

Comment: Yes. "I couldn't find any source" because you hadn't written it yet...  I suspect we will meet again on these boards. ;-)

Comment: @Floris: ahahaha :) Indeed we will.  FWIW, I find that your solution is more elegant.  With my solution, you really have to know the IP toolbox.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. I have updated my solution so it actually works now...

Comment: @Floris: Love it!  I'd up vote it more, but I've already done it yesterday :(

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED** inspired by @rayryeng's complete solution, here is a working (proven) solution - my original had a couple of small errors (as happens when you write Matlab code outside of the Matlab environment...). The advantage of this method is that it doesn't require use of the Image Processing Toolbox.

```
A = double(imread('cameraman.tif'))*(1/256.0); % import, scale to range 0-1
original = A; % keep a copy
T1 = 0.2;
T2 = 0.5; % thresholds

A(A>T2) = 3; % region 3
A(A<T1) = 1; % region 1
A(A~=1 & A~=3) = 2;  % region 2: the rest

% create a "padded" version
Apad = zeros(size(A)+2);
Apad(2:end-1, 2:end-1) = A; % now we have a zero border
nr = size(Apad, 1); % number of rows
numFound = 1; % initially some number > 0
neighbors = [-nr-1, -nr, -nr+1, -1, 1, nr-1, nr, nr+1]; % offset of all neighbors

% loop that does the hard work:
while numFound>0
  f2 = find(Apad==2); % indices of all elements in region 2
  i21 = bsxfun(@plus, f2(:), neighbors); % indices of all neighbors
  convert = find(any(Apad(i21) == 3, 2)); % find all pixels that have a neighbor in region 3
  numFound = numel(convert);
  Apad(f2(convert)) = 3;
end

Apad(Apad==2) = 1; % set remaining "islands" to 1
result = Apad(2:end-1, 2:end-1);

%% display results
figure('position', [100 100 900 300]);
subplot(1,3,1); imagesc(original); axis image; axis off; colormap gray
subplot(1,3,2); imagesc(A); axis image; axis off; colormap jet
subplot(1,3,3); imagesc(result); axis image; axis off; colormap gray
saveas(gcf, 'R1R2.png')
```

The result is (original - three regions - two regions):

[image]

Notice an interesting thing in the pants of the photographer. There are two "region 2" regions in the leg - but only one of them "connects" to the "region 3" between the legs. As a consequence, in the final thresholded image you get one region showing up as bright, and the other as dark. This is indeed the expected behavior - but it's nice confirmation that the algorithm works as advertised.

Comment: I started with exactly the same procedure with `bsxfun`, but stopped midway as I had enough doubts with the question. +1 for similarity in thoughts I guess.

Comment: @Divakar: Yes the algorithm was poorly worded.  Now knowing that my assumptions are correct, I would have completely rewritten the description of the algorithm.  Alas, I am not the OP.

Comment: @Floris  : I've done it in matlab.  that's awesome :)
Thank you so much .